# How should I answer 'Happy New Year'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When someone says, "Happy New Year," how should we answer?

- "Happy new year to you, too."
- Or just: "Happy new year!"

Or in some other way?

Comment: or you can answer "You too" See my question [can-you-reply-you-too-to-wishes-such-as-good-luck](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170/can-you-reply-you-too-to-wishes-such-as-good-luck)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a matter of taste.  The most common reply is an echo of "Happy New Year", but often one will hear "And (also) to you!"  In the interest of being different, I usually reply "Nifty New Year to you."

Comment: "Nifty new year to you" is not at all a particularly idiomatic reply to "Happy New Year", and I wouldn't advise learners to use it. A straightforward "Happy New Year" is much more appropriate in most circumstances.

Comment: I specifically mentioned my idiosyncratic salutation as an example of why it's a matter of preference as opposed to there being a hard and fast rule that one must follow, and did so after also specifically mentioning the two most commonly used replies.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to reply *Happy new year* in English to my students (our new year is Norouz mass.)

In my opinion, "**to you, too**" or "**same to you**" are both OK.

Comment: Earlier, I flagged this post (as "not an answer") because I thought it wasn't an answer. Now I tried to read it again (as suggested by one of our members), I think it's possible that meisam was indeed trying to answer the question. Then again, I'm not really sure. It could look both ways, I guess.

Comment: To me it did sound like an answer right from the first time I read, though in a not-so-common-way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The most common response is to echo back the same thing:  *"Happy New Year!"*

This also applies to any "common" holiday, meaning one that is not personally related to you.  So it's the same for *"Merry/Happy Christmas"*, *"Happy Easter"*, and various country-specific holidays:  *"Happy Thanksgiving"*, *"Happy Fourth of July"*, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I used to say "Happy New Year", but I changed to "Likewise!" as it is shorter and it seems the new years are going to come every year and I don't want to repeat myself yearly.

Hope New Year will be celebrated every 5 years in the future.

Answer (score -2):

The best response for 'happy new year' is 'many happy returns'

Comment: Indeed, although "many happy returns" is much more common in British and Indian English than American English.

Comment: In British English, I've only ever heard "many happy returns" as a synonym for "happy birthday"; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many_happy_returns_%28greeting%29) describes this as "common usage".

Comment: I can't agree that it's "the best response." (I would agree that it's an acceptable response, and I might agree that it's a good response.)

Comment: I think "Many happy returns" is suitable.