# Proper reply for 'Happy Vacations'

Tags: politeness

Someone has messaged me:

> — Happy vacations.

Are the following replies correct?

> — Now it would be good.
>   — Same to you too!

Or it should be

> — Same to you too!
>   — Now it would be good.

I want to sound like, as he has said so, now my vacations will definitely go awesome.
What should be the proper reply?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15132/how-should-i-answer-happy-new-year

Comment: Just a short note about using vacation vs vacations. The word vacation covers a single vacation, whether it lasts a day, a week, or longer. Vacations means two or more separate vacations, like taking one weeklong vacation now, and another a year later. Happy vacation!

Comment: Only use "Same to you too!" if you know they are also leaving on vacation in around the same timeframe as your vacation.  Otherwise wishing them a happy vacation when they aren't taking one is kind of odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a cultural difference perhaps.  When people wish you some type of "good blessing" do you respond with something like "now it will be"?

Mainstream Western culture does not typically do this.  However, that is not to say you shouldn't do so, since that is who you are and **would be** great cultural sharing.

So one typical American way **would be**:

> "Happy vacations."
>
> "Thanks!!!  You too!!!"

An American would not understand your cultural view of things, so if you want to express that, a little more explaining is needed. I think it **would be** great fun for you to send it like this:

> "Happy vacations."
>
> Text 1: "In my culture/country, when one wishes another happy vacations and such, we say "Now it will be good! (Because you wished it for me, now my vacations will definitely go awesome!) Soooooo......"
>
> Text 2: "Thanks! Now it WILL be good!  Happy vacations to you too!"

After that, you can expect the other person to maybe reply, "Thanks! Now mine **will be** good too!  Hehe".

Let us know how it goes! : )

---

By the way, "Now it **would be** good" is incorrect; that is used for a conditional. "Now it **will be** good" is stating a future "fact" or statement with very high confidence.  The phrase "will be", among many uses, is often used in legal contracts and rhetoric.

- Person 1:"I hope I win the lottery." Person 2: "That sure **would be** great."
- "It would be good/great/awesome if we win the lottery tonight."
- "It would be good/great/awesome if I won the lottery."
- "It **will be** such a relief once final exams are over!"
- "The Seller **will not be** responsible for any damages...."
- "We are glad to have made the contract to build a stadium. This **will be** a positive influence on this city's economy for many decades to come..."

Comment: Is there any specific reason for `WILL` instead of `will`.

Comment: Emphasis, like you are saying it with *positive emotion* and a bit louder. It could be translated "now it definitely will be", except even that doesn't have the same *positive emotion* connotation because small case is all flat.  This emphasis will be good since this is the first time you introduced them to the idea: you are asserting it is true. Next time with this person, you won't use that emphasis.